# ssh debug1: ssh_exchange_identification

Tags: ssh

I have a problem with SSH that I've researched for almost a week and i've gotten to the point where I really don't know what to do. I'm participating in a cybersecurity challenge to "understand" a special file server, all I have is Wireshark cpap file.

After carefully analyzing it and finding the "protocol" in which the "special" file server works, I'm trying to communicate with it, but without success. 
the way the server is "talking" to me is by sending the word "welcome!" 
I should then reply with HELLO.

This server is working with ssh, so I'm trying to ssh it, but before I have an opportunity to insert input I get this output

```
ssh -v server -p port
OpenSSH_7.7p1 Debian-2, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server & port  
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1    
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory        
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory    
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7p1 Debian-2
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 0 8 Welcome!

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: 0 18 Error: wrong input
```

So I've researched on the ssh protocol to understand how it handles keys, so I've tried to change my private key to be the word HELLO, to which the server is hoping but it's not working sadly.

Of course, searching for ssh_exchange_identification error gives me results from a lot of people who genuinely have this problem, and not like me where the server is using it as a mechanism to error notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> after carefully analyzing it and finding the "protocol" in which the "special" file server works, im trying to communicate with it, but without success. the way the server is "talking" to me is by sending the word "welcome!" i should then reply with HELLO.

That's not SSH. You can't use a SSH client to perform this part, because it doesn't look anything like the SSH connection handshake. The ssh_exchange_identification error isn't sent by the server; it's generated by your client after it fails to recognize the server protocol.

If your server is built in a way that `HELLO` makes it begin talking SSH *on the same port,* you can perform that part by writing a short script and using it as the SSH ProxyCommand.

Otherwise, make sure that you're SSHing into the correct port. (How did you determine that the server "works with SSH" anyway?)

Comment: first of all, thank you very much for commenting!  
2nd of all i do know that because 1) it says WELCOME, which is the message i was hoping for, and secondly it showed that in wireshark.
i quite didn't understand the part about me sending the string hello to the server, i can't do that from the terminal alone? maybe with command line arguments or something?

Comment: oh! you were totally right!! im so glad you helped me!! i was just needed to nc to that port and it worked! thank you so very much. i could spend days understanding this! :)

Comment: You can do it from the terminal (using nc, telnet, socat...) – just not with ssh.

Comment: yes you were totally right! thank you so much!